# Swagger Token error (Unsupported_Grant_Type)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have set up the token correctly in Postman and the authorization token is present in my Asp.net SQL server Database. but, when I want to get Swagger Authorization Token it gives me the error: {
"error": "unsupported_grant_type"
} on swagger:
the following is the code I wrote and the picture.
thank you in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB7JB.png)

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the headers in working request with non working request. The default headers in one application may not be the same as another application.  It sound like you are either missing a header or the default value of a header is wrong.

Comment: To Use token (if already generated) use Header for `{ "Authorization" : "Bearer [your-generated-token]"`
While grant_type along with credentials can be used to generate new token hence not needed